# Fixed positioned div with a fixed height and relative or absolute divs inside it with greater height

Tags: internet-explorer-8, position, fixed

I have a problem with IE.

I have a fixed div like this:

```
#fixed {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 9998;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
}
```

Inside this div I want to place another div that has a height that is higher than its holder (higher than 40px). So I put a relative or an absolute div inside it and it works splendid in all browsers except IE, at least IE8.

But in IE8 the child div gets cut because of the height of 40px specified for it's holder.

Is there any workaround to this problem? I'm starting to get gray hairs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick reply: have you tried setting the [`clip`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pos_clip.asp) property of the contained div to it's own size?

Another workaround would be (if, say you have a container div with left/right margins `auto` and `position: relative`) to have the second div outside the fixed `div` in your HTML, then position it `fixed` within the container div instead - since it's also fixed, you can then set top/bottom and left/right positions to suit.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this! The clip property solved it for me!!!

But still amazed that I spend a third of development time to adjust to the incompetent IE browser.......

Anyway, thanks

Comment: Hmm, now I detected that this didn't work in IE7.. I guess it's because I add the Clip property to a fixed position div..

Comment: If the previous code worked for IE7, try loading the new clip CSS with a conditional comment just for IE8?